# I2Cmaster with MPU6050 in VHDL not working

Tags: vhdl, fpga, i2c, quartus, mpu6050

For my hobby project I try to make a quadcopter which balances itself with the MPU-6050. The flight controller shall be the FPGA Altera cyclone IV, because its fun. I'm coding it in VHDL.

Anyway I'm stuck on the I2C communication with the MPU-6050. As bases I used the I2C master VHDL code from: https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=10125324.

I try to read the gyro registers and print them out on 8 leds just to see if I have some communication coming in.

I have tried to run with a 1Hz prescaler all the I2C phases in the state machine and light up some leds just to see if all phases are run through. This is the case. I have assigned the pins 2.5V default, I use 10k pull up resistors. The MPU6050 works perferct on an arduino.

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

     entity mpu6050_2 is
    port( clk_50 : in std_logic;
            areset : in std_logic;  
            i2c_SDA : INOUT  STD_LOGIC;
            i2c_SCL : INOUT  STD_LOGIC;
            leds : out std_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
     );
     end entity mpu6050_2;

     architecture struc of mpu6050_2 is

     component i2c_master is
     GENERIC(
     input_clk : INTEGER := 50_000_000; 
     bus_clk   : INTEGER := 400_000);   
     PORT(
      clk       : IN     STD_LOGIC;                   
      reset_n   : IN     STD_LOGIC;                   
      ena       : IN     STD_LOGIC;                   
      addr      : IN     STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0); 
      rw        : IN     STD_LOGIC;                    
      data_wr   : IN     STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);  
      busy      : OUT    STD_LOGIC;     
      data_rd   : OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
      ack_error : BUFFER STD_LOGIC;  
      sda       : INOUT  STD_LOGIC;                    
      scl       : INOUT  STD_LOGIC);       
      end component ;

      type machine is (config1, config2, gyroH, gyroL);
      signal state  : machine:= config1; --current state

      signal SDA_int : std_LOGIC;
      signal SCL_int : std_LOGIC;
      signal i2c_ena : std_LOGIC;
      signal i2c_busy : std_LOGIC;
      signal busy_prev : std_LOGIC;
      signal i2c_rw : std_LOGIC;
      signal i2c_data_wr : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
      signal gyro_data : std_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
      signal i2c_data_rd : std_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
      signal i2c_addr : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0);


begin

process(areset, clk_50) 

    VARIABLE busy_cnt  : INTEGER := 0;  --keeps track of i2c busy signals during transaction

    begin

    if areset = '0' then
        busy_cnt := 0; 
        i2c_ena <= '0';
        state <= config1;

    elsif rising_edge(clk_50) then

        case state is

        when config1 =>
            busy_prev <= i2c_busy;
            if (busy_prev = '0' and i2c_busy = '1') then
                busy_cnt := busy_cnt + 1;
            end if;

                case busy_cnt is
                    when 0 =>
                        i2c_ena <= '1';
                        i2c_addr <= "1101000"; --MPU6050 adress
                        i2c_rw <= '0'; --write
                        i2c_data_wr <= x"6B"; -- hex6B powermanagement          
                    when 1 =>
                        i2c_rw <= '0'; --write
                        i2c_data_wr <= "00000000"; -- ON with internal clock
                    when 2 =>
                            i2c_ena <= '0';
                            if(i2c_busy = '0') then
                                busy_cnt := 0;
                                state <= config2;
                            end if;

                    when others => NULL;
                end case;       

        when config2 =>
            busy_prev <= i2c_busy;
            if (busy_prev = '0' and i2c_busy = '1') then
                busy_cnt := busy_cnt + 1;
            end if;

                case busy_cnt is
                    when 0 =>
                        i2c_ena <= '1';
                        i2c_addr <= "1101000"; --MPU6050 adress
                        i2c_rw <= '0'; --write
                        i2c_data_wr <= x"1B"; -- Gyro config            
                    when 1 =>
                        i2c_rw <= '0'; --write
                        i2c_data_wr <= "00000000"; -- 250 degree/sec, no self test
                    when 2 =>
                            i2c_ena <= '0';
                            if(i2c_busy = '0') then
                                busy_cnt := 0;
                                state <= gyroH;
                            end if;
                    when others => NULL;
                end case;               


        when gyroH =>
            busy_prev <= i2c_busy;
            if (busy_prev = '0' and i2c_busy = '1') then
                busy_cnt := busy_cnt + 1;
            end if;

                case busy_cnt is
                    when 0 =>
                        i2c_ena <= '1';
                        i2c_addr <= "1101000"; --MPU6050 adress
                        i2c_rw <= '0'; --write
                        i2c_data_wr <= x"43"; -- hex43 GYRO_OUT[15:8]           
                    when 1 =>
                        i2c_rw <= '1'; --read
                    when 2 =>
                            i2c_ena <= '0';
                        if(i2c_busy = '0') then
                            gyro_data(15 downto 8) <= i2c_data_rd;
                            busy_cnt := 0;
                            state <= gyroL;
                        end if;
                    when others => NULL;
                end case;

        when gyroL =>   
            busy_prev <= i2c_busy;
            if (busy_prev = '0' and i2c_busy = '1') then
                busy_cnt := busy_cnt + 1;
            end if;

                case busy_cnt is
                    when 0 =>
                        i2c_ena <= '1';
                        i2c_addr <= "1101000"; --MPU6050 adress
                        i2c_rw <= '0'; --write
                        i2c_data_wr <= x"44"; -- hex44 GYRO_OUT[7:0]            
                    when 1 =>
                        i2c_rw <= '1'; --read
                    when 2 =>
                            i2c_ena <= '0';
                        if(i2c_busy = '0') then
                            gyro_data(7 downto 0) <= i2c_data_rd;
                            busy_cnt := 0;
                            state <= gyroH; 
                        end if;

                    when others => NULL;
                end case;           

        end case;
    end if;

end process;

u0: i2c_master
port map(clk => clk_50, reset_n => areset, ena => i2c_ena, addr => i2c_addr, rw => i2c_rw, data_wr => i2c_data_wr, busy => i2c_busy, data_rd => i2c_data_rd
, sda => SDA_int, scl => SCL_int);

leds(7) <= gyro_data(0); --D4 
leds(6) <= gyro_data(1); -- D5 
leds(5) <= gyro_data(4); -- D6 
leds(4) <= gyro_data(7); -- D7 
leds(3) <= gyro_data(8);  -- D8 
leds(2) <= gyro_data(11); -- D9
leds(1) <= gyro_data(13); -- D10
leds(0) <= gyro_data(15); -- D11

i2c_SDA <= SDA_int;
i2c_SCL <= SCL_int;


end struc;
```

Result:
all the leds dont change status despite if i rotate the MPU6050. So no communication. Can anyone help me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does your test bench say?

Comment: testbench shows that that all states( config, gyroH, gyroL) are beeing processed as expected. However it seems that the i2cmaster keeps on being stuck in the "ready" state. Which means the enable (ena) is never '1'. I dont understand why. Its also weird that all stages are beeing processed (config, gyroL and gyroH) while busy in the i2cmaster stays 0. SCL clock is nicely 400kHz, so I guess I simulated it correctly.

Comment: The i2c_master.vhdl (Version 2.2) is not valid VHDL. IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.9 Case statement "All simple expressions and discrete ranges given as choices in a case statement shall be locally static. A choice defined by a discrete range stands for all values in the corresponding range." E.g. `WHEN 0 TO divider-1 =>`  line 86, where `divider` is globally static (`CONSTANT divider  :  INTEGER := (input_clk/bus_clk)/4;`, both `input_clk` and `bus_clk` are generic constants). What testbench and whose simulator?

Comment: @user1155120: yes, this is correct. The choices are not locally static and need to be replaced by `if`...`else`...`end if` constructs. Other than that, the i2c master works fine

Comment: @mfro Your answer sounds plausible but the question provides neither a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (no testbench or patched i2c_master.vhd ) nor does your answer provide enough information for future readers to benefit from you experience lacking information on the [device operation](https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf)  and [i2C bus](http://cache.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf). Simulate for 1 ms - 5 ms and the waveforms can demonstrate problem and solution to others besides the OP. You could even force the ACKs at the right times.

Answer (score 1):

First: I'm using the same component in one of my designs and do confirm it works.

I think you are just using the wrong i2c address to begin with.

In datasheets, i2c addresses are usually given including the read/write bit (for the MPU-6050, this is `0x68/01101000` and `0x69/01101001`). The i2c master component used, however, expects to build the final i2c address by itself by appending (`&`) the i2c rw bit to the given address (see line 124 in the original sources), thus you must pass the address from the datasheet shifted by one bit.

Try using `0x34/0110100` as i2c address for read and write instead.

I only looked very briefly into the rest of your code (so there might be other culprits as well), but this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: so at the moment I fixed some bugs, and according to my testbench the code should work perfectly, only no communication yet. At the moment I send adress 1101000 is this sequence followed by a read or write bit, so 11010001 or 11010000. P.S. I tried 01101000 but that didnt work.

Comment: you need to use `0110100` as `addr` (note: it is a `std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)`). Once the `rw` bit gets appended, you end up with `01101000`/`01101001` which is correct. If it still doesn't work then, you have other errors as well.